# Converting hash table to list of pairs (key,value) in OCaml

Tags: list, hashtable, ocaml

Is there a way of converting a hash table into a list of (key,pair) values in OCaml?

I'm aware that, given a hash table `ht` we can do

```
BatList.of_enum (BatHashtbl.enum ht)
```

using the batteries library. This would convert the table to an enumeration and then convert the enum to a list. But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use the Batteries Library. In the [standard OCaml Hashtbl Module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html) there doesn't seem to be a way of extracting the pairs as a list or a way of combining its functions to achieve this purpose. Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, I think that saying in the question where you looked (as you did here) is very good practice: it help provide an answer at the right level, show that you have tried, and saved me the time to look up the type of Hashtbl.fold :) (that I do not know by heart, but as a rule of thumb, when it's called `fold` the type is that of `fold_right`)

Answer (score 31):

> In the standard OCaml Hashtbl Module there doesn't seem to be ...

Of couse there is!

```
val fold : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'c) -> ('a, 'b) t -> 'c -> 'c
```

So, use:

```
fun h -> Hashtbl.fold (fun k v acc -> (k, v) :: acc) h []
```